# invoking /flashservices/gateway from flash

Tags: flash, coldfusion, coldfusion-8, jrun

We currently have 2 servers running the same (as far as I can tell) configuration of ColdFusion 8:

- Same data source configuration
- Same mappings
- Same JVM configuration
- Same folder structure
- Same code

We are using Flash remoting to customize flash assets with the data of one component.

On one server, the calls are working fine:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Length: 298
Content-Type: application/x-amf
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With
Date: Thu, 10 Jan 2013 13:12:11 GMT

������
/1/onResult�null���������COPYTEXT�JIf ...
```

The same call the to the other is failing:

```
<head><title>JRun Servlet Error</title></head><h1>500 </h1><body>
<br><pre>
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at jrun.servlet.JRunRequestDispatcher.invoke(JRunRequestDispatcher.java:285)
    at jrun.servlet.ServletEngineService.dispatch(ServletEngineService.java:543)
    at jrun.servlet.jrpp.JRunProxyService.invokeRunnable(JRunProxyService.java:203)
    at jrunx.scheduler.ThreadPool$DownstreamMetrics.invokeRunnable(ThreadPool.java:320)
    at jrunx.scheduler.ThreadPool$ThreadThrottle.invokeRunnable(ThreadPool.java:428)
    at jrunx.scheduler.ThreadPool$UpstreamMetrics.invokeRunnable(ThreadPool.java:266)
    at jrunx.scheduler.WorkerThread.run(WorkerThread.java:66)
</pre></body>
```

As mentioned, I compared to configuration of both boxes and both seem fine.

I also added logging code to the called component. On the working machine, the logging is done. On the failing machine, no log is generated. Therefore, I suspect that the code does not get evaluated at all.

Any lead will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While checking deeper into the ColdFusion logs, it appeared that the JRUN logs where full of the below errors:

```
01/10 14:01:25 user FlashGateway: init
01/10 14:01:25 user failed to load: flashgateway.controller.GatewayServlet
01/10 14:01:25 error [Flash Remoting MX]-> Unable to load configuration. Reason: The string "--" is not permitted within comments.
[1]flashgateway.GatewayException: [Flash Remoting MX]-> Unable to load configuration. Reason: The string "--" is not permitted within comments.
```

Then using comparing the two configuration files, there was one character difference between the two configuration files: \wwwroot\WEB-INF\gateway-config.xml
Failing machine:

```
<!---<adapter>coldfusion.flash.adapter.CFWSAdapter</adapter>--->
```

Working machine:

```
<!---<adapter>coldfusion.flash.adapter.CFWSAdapter</adapter>-->
```

Removing the extra dash (ColdFusion closing comment to HTML closing comment) fixed the issue.